# Mesh lagging behind another mesh in the same target bone

Tags: armature

I am currently making a hinge armature and there are a few meshes that is attached to the target bone (via object constraints). It looks like this:

[image: The Suspension Armature]

However, when I rotate the selected bone on the X-Axis to move the hinge up and down, the tracks lag behind the rest of the other objects:

[image: Lagging Behind]

I have tried to weight paint all of them equally but it still prevails the same issue. The track has is parented to the curve and no object is parented to the armature (except the circular and box empties). Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found out while accidentally messing around with the object constraint. I noticed the main gear piece was going **in front** of the armature itself. I set the bone influence to `0` on the object and now its moving with the bone properly.